Neglected Term in the energy gradient for Variational Monte-Carlo
I'm looking into variational Monte-Carlo to determine the optimal variational parameter that corresponds to the ground state of a Hamiltonian.  In general I am interested in tight binding models where there is hopping in the lattice.
The energy is:
$$E = \langle H \rangle = \frac{\langle \psi^\dagger H \psi \rangle}{\langle \psi^\dagger \psi \rangle}$$
In the position basis this is massaged into the monte carlo integration friendly form
$$E = \frac{\sum_x |\psi(x)|^2 E_l(x)}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2}$$,
where $E_l = \sum_y H(x,y) \psi(y)/\psi(x)$,
and $H(x,y)$ is a matrix element of the Hamiltonian in the position basis.  Let's say that $\psi(x)$ depends on a variational paramter, $\theta$.  We are interested in finding the value of $\theta$ that corresponds to the ground state so we perform gradient descent to minimize the energy.  The derivative of the energy with respect to the variational parameter is
$$\partial_{\theta} E = \partial_{\theta}\frac{\sum_x |\psi(x)|^2 E_l(x)}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2}$$
which is calculated out to be
$$\frac{\sum_x [\partial_{\theta}\psi(x)^*\psi(x)+\partial_{\theta}\psi(x)\psi(x)^*]  E_l(x)}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2} - \frac{\sum_x [\psi(x)^*\psi(x)E_l(x)]\sum_z [\partial_{\theta}\psi(z)^*\psi(z)+\partial_{\theta}\psi(z)\psi(z)^*] }{[\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2]^2} + \frac{\sum_x |\psi(x)|^2 \partial_{\theta} E_l(x)}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2}$$
The first two terms are cited to be the derivative of the energy in the literature.  Explicitly the derivative is often written as
$$\partial_{\theta} E=2\langle \partial_\theta[\text{ln}(\psi)] E_l\rangle - 2E \langle \partial_\theta[\text{ln}(\psi)]\rangle. \quad\text{(for real $\psi$)}$$
The third term is, however, almost always neglected.  Computing out the third term we have
$$\frac{\sum_x |\psi(x)|^2 \partial_{\theta} [\sum_y \frac{H(x,y)\psi(y)}{\psi(x)}]}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2} = \frac{\sum_x |\psi(x)|^2 [\sum_y \frac{H(x,y)\psi(y)}{\psi(x)} \partial_{\theta}\left[\text{ln}\left(\frac{\psi(y)}{\psi(x)}\right)\right]]}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2}.$$
For local Hamiltonians this term above is clearly zero, but if there is hopping then it is not zero (i.e. $H(x,y)$ contains terms like $\delta_{x+1, y}$).  For some reason, however, this term is never written down in the literature even when considering systems with hopping or general off diagonal $H(x,y)$ (at least from what I have studied so far).  What gives? Have I made a mistake?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

While your approach is technically correct, isolating $E_l$ during the calculations is not judicious. It is best to keep things explicit and identify it at the very end. Just rewriting it in general:
$$
E[\psi]=\frac{\sum_{x,y}\psi(x)^*H(x,y)\psi(y)}{\sum_{z}|\psi(z)|^2}
$$
In the same spirit of the linked paper without restricting to real wave functions:
$$
\begin{align}
dE &= \frac1{\sum_{z}|\psi(z)|^2}\sum_x d\psi(x)^*\left(-E\psi(x)+\sum_yH(x,y)\psi(y)\right)+d\psi(x)\left(-E\psi(x)^*+\sum_y \psi(y)^*H(y,x)\right)\\
&= \langle E_l d\ln\psi^*\rangle+\langle E_l^*d\ln\psi\rangle-E\langle d\ln|\psi^2|\rangle
\end{align}
$$
Where:
$$
E_l^*=\sum_y \frac{\psi(y)^*}{\psi(x)^*}H(y,x)
$$
because $H$ is hermitian so $H(x,y)=H(y,x)^*$.
Thus, formula from the literature is exact, no neglected terms. By analogy with statistical physics, the first two term would correspond to energy and the second one to free energy (partition function) giving you maximum entropy.
Your approach is harder because you artificially asymmetrize the role between $\psi$ and $\psi^*$. Perhaps you had another formula in mind from another article, but there is no natural term
$$
\langle E_ld\ln|\psi|^2\rangle = \langle E_l d\ln\psi^*\rangle+\langle E_ld\ln\psi\rangle
$$
Perhaps you generalized a bit too fast the real case? The third term is necessary to recover the correct formula (you need to use again the fact that $H$ is hermitian):
$$
\langle dE_l\rangle = -\langle E_l d\ln\psi^*\rangle+\langle E_l^*d\ln\psi\rangle
$$
Note that this is still consistent with the article. For a real $\psi=\psi^*$, the third term does cancel.

Thanks for the response! Isolating $E_l$ is necessary in VMC because we wish to compute the energy via monte-Carlo integration  (i.e using importance sampling via the distribution $\psi^2/ \sum |\psi|^2$). The expression I quoted (and equivalent variants) is basically everywhere in the literature. See for example: https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/web.sas.upenn.edu/dist/c/190/files/2019/10/Lin00p2650.pdf

Using the same importance sampling we also compute the energy gradient via Monte-Carlo integration during the VMC algorithm (that’s why the form of the gradient looks a bit contrived)

Thanks for checking out the article!  I was being a bit sloppy in my original question and assumed that $E_l$ was real (true for the problems I am investigating), hence the $\langle E_l \partial_{\theta} \text{ln}|\psi|^2\rangle$ term.
So, if I am not mistaken, are you saying that the correct full form for the energy derivative for a complex trial wavefunction with a (real) local energy would be exactly what I wrote down?

Your equations are always correct, it's just that your identified third term is zero for real wavefuntions.

By local energy, you mean a diagonal Hamiltonian in position basis? (e.g. nearest hopping are often considered as local) In general the Hamiltonian's form is not relevant, only the fact that it is hermitian.

Thank you for your answer, this was very helpful!

As LPZ mentioned, a key step you were missing was not using the reality condition $\psi^\star=\psi$. I think that answer is completely correct, I just wanted to add some details.
I also want to add that I don't think introducing $E_l(x)$ before taking the derivative helps in this particular calculation. You can directly differentiate
$$
E = \frac{\sum_{x} \sum_y \psi(x) H(x,y) \psi(y)}{\sum_x \psi(x)^2}
$$
To introduce $E_l(x)$, you need to multiply the numerator and denominator by $\psi(x)$ and then separate one of those factors into $E_l(x)$. That's inevitably going to make the algebra more complicated, since somehow this simple cancellation has to show up when you take the derivatives of different terms.
First, let me introduce some notation
$$
\partial_\theta E = T_1 + T_2 + T_3
$$
where
\begin{eqnarray}
T_1 &\equiv& \frac{\sum_x [\partial_{\theta}\psi(x)^*\psi(x)+\partial_{\theta}\psi(x)\psi(x)^*]  E_l(x)}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2} \\
T_2 &\equiv& - \frac{\sum_x [\psi(x)^*\psi(x)E_l(x)]\sum_z [\partial_{\theta}\psi(z)^*\psi(z)+\partial_{\theta}\psi(z)\psi(z)^*] }{[\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2]^2} \\
T_3 &\equiv&  \frac{\sum_x |\psi(x)|^2 \partial_{\theta} E_l(x)}{\sum_j |\psi(j)|^2}
\end{eqnarray}
I'm also going to introduce the normalization factor
$$
\mathcal{N} \equiv \sum_j |\psi(j)|^2
$$
Now using the reality condition, we can make some simplifications.
\begin{eqnarray}
T_1 &=& \frac{2\sum_x \psi(x) E_l(x) \partial_\theta \psi(x)}{\mathcal{N}} = 2\frac{\sum_x \psi(x)^2 E_l(x) \partial_\theta \ln \psi(x)}{\mathcal{N}} = 2\langle E_l(x) \partial_\theta \ln \psi \rangle \\
T_2 &=& -\frac{\sum_x \psi^2(x)E_l(x) \partial_\theta \mathcal{N}}{\left|\mathcal{N}\right|^2} = - 2 E \langle \partial_\theta \ln \psi \rangle
\end{eqnarray}
where the last equality with $T_2$ involves expanding out $\partial_\theta \mathcal{N}$ and using $\sum_x \psi(x) \partial_\theta \psi(x) = \sum_x \psi(x)^2 \partial_\theta \ln \psi(x)$.
Now, we come to the infamous $T_3$. We first expand it out it as you did
$$
T_3 = \frac{\sum_x \sum_y \psi(x)^2 \frac{H(x,y) \psi(y)}{\psi(x)} \partial_\theta \ln\left(\frac{\psi(y)}{\psi(x)}\right)}{\mathcal{N}}
$$
However, this is not the simplest form we can put it in. In this form, we notice the $\psi^2(x)$ in the numerator (of the numerator) cancels with $\psi(x)$ in the denominator (of the numerator). We also can use $\partial_\theta\ln(A/B) = \partial_\theta\ln A - \partial_\theta \ln B = \frac{\partial_\theta A}{A} - \frac{\partial_\theta B}{B}$. This will also lead to some cancellations. Carrying all of those steps out, we get
$$
T_3 = \frac{\sum_x \sum_y H(x,y) \psi(y) \partial_\theta \psi(x) - \psi(x) H(x,y) \partial_\theta \psi(y)}{\mathcal{N}}
$$
Now, since $H$ is a hermitian operator, $H(x,y)=H(y,x)$, so we can relabel the dummy indices $x\leftrightarrow y$ in one of the terms above. After doing that, it is obvious that
$$
T_3 = 0
$$
Note that we can interpret $T_3=\langle \partial_\theta E_l\rangle$, so we are also saying that $\langle \partial_\theta E_l\rangle=0$. This essentially happens because the first order variation of $\psi(y)$ in the numerator cancels with the first order variation of $\psi(x)$ in the denominator, after accounting for the double sum and hermiticity of $H$.
Thus, putting it all together, we get the expected form
$$
\partial_\theta E = 2\langle E_l(x) \partial_\theta \ln \psi \rangle - 2 E \langle \partial_\theta \ln \psi \rangle
$$
If you want, you could check how the above calculation works out for complex $\psi$.

Thank you this was very helpful!
